# How to redirect http port to Docker in Azure's Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-machine

I have Ubuntu running on a Microsoft Azure's virtual machine. I have a **docker container** running on it, and it has a web server attached to it. (Running on 172.17.0.1:80)

[image: Here is the index.html on SSH]

Now I'm trying to make it accessible publicly, using the Azure's public IP[image: This IP definitively works, since I'm SSHing on it.]

In the Networking settings, I have tried to create an inbound port rule[image: On Azure's dashboard]

But it's not working...

I've tried tracert to see where my ping goes when I try to connect to the IP, with no result.
I've done basic port routing in the past, but I can't figure out why this one is not working...
I just want to type 13.94.212.10 on my personal connection, and access the website.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the application on your Azure VM publicly with its public Ip address.

You could whitelist you client public IP in the NSG rule like, add the client public IP in the `Source IP addresses`.

[image]

Please note that

> If you specify an address for an Azure resource, specify the private
> IP address assigned to the resource. Network security groups are
> processed after Azure translates a public IP address to a private IP
> address for inbound traffic, and before Azure translates a private IP
> address to a public IP address for outbound traffic.

Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview#security-rules

Comment: I have created the rule just as you told me, but it stills does not work...

Comment: Any error message? if it's a network-related issue. Is there any firewall inside the Azure VM blocking it? You could read this blog--- [Host Your Static Website in Azure as a Docker Container](https://medium.com/better-programming/host-your-static-website-in-azure-as-a-docker-container-be127f00267d) for more references. Do you add the correct client IP? You could check it with https://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: Oh crap, I tried to edit my comment but got an error, it's working now, but I have no idea why, I have changed so many things... Thank you so much for your answer!